# how do I stop dnf from fetch remote metadata during dnf list or other subcommand that only need local database?

Tags: dnf

From time to time when I call dnf it will try to download remote metadata regardless what subcommand I am calling, I wonder how can I disable this? It takes very long to get all metadata but actually I only want some local info. Is there any flag to suppress this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `dnf` with `-C`/`--cacheonly` to tell it to not download new metadata.

> Run entirely from system cache, don't update the cache and use it even in case it is expired.
> DNF uses a separate cache for each user under which it executes. The cache for the root user is called the system cache. This switch allows a regular user  read-only  access  to  the  system cache, which usually is more fresh than the user's and thus he does not have to wait for metadata sync.